# Compact VirtualBox disk images which are not attached but still have child images

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, images

I have been creating some VMs on the fly: set up one, created a snapshot, made a few changes, cloned it, repeated the process with the clone, and then with a clone of the clone etc.

After cleaning up some unneeded VMs, I now have some disk images in my Virtual Media Manager that are no longer attached to anything but still have child images, so I cannot delete them.

The tree roughly looks like this:

- `original.vdi`, attached to original VM

  - `{08932168-600d-beef-cafe-950824113607.vdi}`, attached to original VM

    - `{15552878-d00d-fa1a-fe15-badd0990f00d.vdi}`, not attached (formerly a snapshot of a since-deleted VM)

      - `{d09905e2-f00d-aca7-1e55-babefee15bad.vdi}`, attached to a still-in-use VM

Now, obviously `15552878` may have some data that is still needed by `d09905e2` but not in that image, nor do any of the parent images `08932168` or `original` have an up-to-date version of that data, so we can’t simply delete that image.

On the other hand, some of the data `15552878` may be overridden by `d09905e2` and thus obsolete, so in theory we should be able to compact `15552878`, dropping these sectors, or merge whatever data in `15552878` is still in use into `d09905e2`.

Any way to do that in VirtualBox? I have tried `vboxmanage modifyhd ... compact` as well as `vboxmanage modifymedium --compact`, both on the unattached image and its child, to no avail – size does not change.

Comment: Did you combine or delete the snapshots before moving forward?  If not, I am not sure how you get out of this.

Comment: I didn’t, just deleted the VMs I no longer needed, hoping VirtualBox would sort these things out or at least let me do that later...

Comment: ...and, digging a bit deeper, I don’t see any option to combine snapshots either.

Comment: Apparently no such thing in VBOX. Follow this article to see if it helps you. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=98067#:~:text=Re%3A%20Merge%20snapshot%20in%20Virtualbox%20%3F&text=There%20is%20no%20such%20thing,will%20lose%20all%20your%20work.